# How to rollup data points using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Say I have an array of 6 numeric data points and want to change it to an array of 3 data points where each point is the sum of a 2 of the points

[1,1,1,1,1,1] ~> [2,2,2]

What is the best way to do this with a library like underscore.js

Comment: Which 2 older points are the newer points supposed to sum up? Does [0] map to ([0]+[1]), [1] map to ([2]+[3]), etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it in a generic, functional way, then

```
function allowIndexes(idx) {
    return function(item, index) {
        return index % idx;
    }
}

function sum() {
    return _.reduce(_.toArray(arguments)[0], function(result, current) {
        return result + current;
    }, 0);
}

var isIndexOdd = allowIndexes(2);

var zipped = _.zip(_.reject(data, isIndexOdd), _.filter(data, isIndexOdd));
console.log(_.map(zipped, sum));
# [ 3, 7, 11 ]
```

But, this will be no where near the performance of

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    result.push(data[i] + data[i + 1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way. I'll gladly accept a better solution.

```
    values = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
    reportingPeriod = 2;
    var combined = [];
    _.inject( values, function ( total, value, index) {
        if ((index + 1) % reportingPeriod === 0) {
            combined.push(total + value);
            return 0;
        } else {
            return total + value
        }
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, you could do the following:

```
let arr = _.fill(Array(6), 1);
let reducer = (sum, num) => sum += num;
arr = _.chain(arr).chunk(2).map(arr => arr.reduce(reducer)).value();
```